# Why false = true is giving true as a result

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          boolean isJavaFun = true;
          boolean isFishTasty = false;    
          System.out.println(isFishTasty = isJavaFun);
          System.out.println(isFishTasty);
     }
}
```

System.out.println(isFishTasty = isJavaFun); is givinh true, not sure why?

Comment: `=` is assignment operator which *also returns assigned value*, here `isJavaFun` which holds `true`. `==` is comparison operator.

Comment: Because `=` is  assignment, not comparison.